# Is there a wildcard type variable in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to be able to polymorphically handle multiple `Either` values who share the same `Left` type, but not the same `Right` type, e.g.:

```
foo = Left "foo" :: Either String Int
bar = Left "bar" :: Either String Char
list = [foo, bar]
```

The `Left` value indicates an error message in case the computation failed, while the `Right` value has different types depending on different computations. In case of failure I only care about gathering the errors on the left, so it would be useful to be able to treat all of them the same for this purpose.

However, this fails, and the compiler expects both type variables to match:

```
    * Couldn't match type `Char' with `Int'
      Expected type: Either String Int
        Actual type: Either String Char
    * In the expression: bar
      In the expression: [foo, bar]
      In an equation for `list': list = [foo, bar]
```

After a lot of searching, the only thing I stumbled upon is something called a "Partial Type Signature", which uses the "_" wildcard, and has to be enabled explicitly by a flag for it to compile. However, even after enabling it, it still doesn't seem to change anything:

```
foo = Left "foo" :: Either String Int
bar = Left "bar" :: Either String Char
list = [foo, bar] :: Either String _
```

And I receive the same error:

```
    * Couldn't match type `Char' with `Int'
      Expected type: Either String Int
        Actual type: Either String Char
    * In the expression: bar
      In the expression: [foo, bar] :: Either String _
      In an equation for `list': list = [foo, bar] :: Either String _
```

In Java (if it had an `Either` type), I could simply do something like this:

```
List<Either<String, ?>> list = asList(foo, bar);
```

And it would have worked just fine, type safe and whatnot.

Is there a type variable wildcard in Haskell corresponding to `?` in Java? If not, how do you deal with such cases where you don't care about a certain type variable and want to abstract it? Is there an alternative?

**More details:**

Realizing that I wasn't clear enough about my problem, I will elaborate:

What I'm trying to implement is a command line parser. It should receive the user's input (command line arguments) and return a `Params` value, where:

```
data Params = Params String Double Bool
```

For simplicity's sake I only included 3 values in the value constructor above, but actually there are many more.

Since there are many different parameters, each one can fail in its own way - the user might not provide the necessary argument, the provided argument is invalid, etc.

The parsing should succeed only if **all** of the arguments provided are valid. If any of them is invalid, then the entire computation should fail. So I thought about the following solution (again, it's simplified, so please ignore other issues like efficiency):

```
parse :: [String] -> Either [String] Params
parse args = if successful
             then Right (Params strParam doubleParam boolParam)
             else Left errors
    where successful = null errors
          (Right strParam) = eitherStr
          (Right doubleParam) = eitherDouble
          (Right boolParam) = eitherBool
          errors = lefts [eitherStr, eitherDouble, eitherBool]
          eitherStr = parseStr args
          eitherDouble = parseDouble args
          eitherBool = parseBool args

parseStr :: [String] -> Either String String
parseDouble :: [String] -> Either String Double
parseBool :: [String] -> Either String Bool
```

But it doesn't compile, since I can't handle `eitherStr`, `eitherDouble` and  `eitherBool` as having the same type, which would have been possible if there was a wildcard type variable. Hence my question.

Under the current circumstances, I have to resort to something like this:

```
parse :: [String] -> Either [String] Params
parse args = if successful
             then Right (Params strParam doubleParam boolParam)
             else Left errors
    where successful = null errors
          (Right strParam) = eitherStr
          (Right doubleParam) = eitherDouble
          (Right boolParam) = eitherBool
          errors = concat [strErrors, doubleErrors, boolErrors]
          strErrors = getErrors eitherStr
          doubleErrors = getErrors eitherDouble
          boolErrors = getErrors eitherBool
          eitherStr = parseStr args
          eitherDouble = parseDouble args
          eitherBool = parseBool args
          getErrors = lefts . (:[])

parseStr :: [String] -> Either String String
parseDouble :: [String] -> Either String Double
parseBool :: [String] -> Either String Bool
```

Doable, but messier. Of course, it's possible that my solution is completely off track, and there's a better idiomatic functional solution, which I'll be glad to hear about.

It was said that Java has `Object` as a universal upper bound, so the comparison is misleading. But it seems to me that there can always be a theoretical upper bound, even if in the worst case that upper bound means a value which you can't use. Which is just fine for cases where you don't need it, such as mine.

**After trying existential types:**

Existential types are of no help to me. They define a new type that wraps the old one, so functions that accept `Either` won't accept the new type, and can't be reused. So instead of using the existing `lefts` function, I have to implement it myself for the new type, in addition to the hassle of defining a new type:

```
data SomeEither l = forall r. SomeEither (Either l r)
data Params = Params String Double Bool deriving (Show)

parse :: [String] -> Either [String] Params
parse args = if successful
             then Right (Params strParam doubleParam boolParam)
             else Left errors
    where successful = null errors
          (Right strParam) = eitherStr
          (Right doubleParam) = eitherDouble
          (Right boolParam) = eitherBool
          errors = lefts' [SomeEither eitherStr, SomeEither eitherDouble, SomeEither eitherBool]
          eitherStr = parseStr args
          eitherDouble = parseDouble args
          eitherBool = parseBool args

lefts' :: [SomeEither l] -> [l]
lefts' [] = []
lefts' ((SomeEither (Left l)):xs) = l:(lefts' xs)
lefts' (x:xs) = lefts' xs

parseStr :: [String] -> Either String String
parseDouble :: [String] -> Either String Double
parseBool :: [String] -> Either String Bool
```

The whole point was to do less work and have cleaner code. The use of existential types in this case does the opposite.

Comment: You might need an existential type to wrap your `Either`s, and then write `[MyExType]`. It is not as convenient as in Java since we do not have subtyping, hence some wrapping is mandatory.

Comment: The Java example is misleading. You can declare generic types with wildcards, but creating a value of such a type always uses a specific type as a bound. Here the compiler infers `List<Either<String, Object>>`, because Object is the least upper bound. It's the presence of a universal supertype (and subtyping in general) that makes this possible, not the presence of wildcard types.

Comment: In case of failure, you only care about gathering the `String`s on the left.  What are you planning to do in case of success, when you're stuck with a heterogeneous list of different types on the right?  I think the answer to that will determine the best solution.

Comment: @amalloy No, that's wrong. Java wildcards bind tightly. `List<Either<String, ?>>` means `[exists r. Either String r]` in pseudo-Haskell. Each of `foo`, `bar` is upcast to `Either<String, ?>`, which is a "normal" type, before being stuck inside the list. You are implying it means `exists r. [Either String r]`, which is not directly expressible in Java. Now, since `Either` is (morally) covariant, the distinction is pretty much not-there, but e.g. with `List<UnaryOperator<?>>`, your interpretation implies you could chain all the elements together, but actually each one can have a different type.

Comment: @HTNW What I'm saying is that you can write `ArrayList<Either<String, ?>> xs;`, but you cannot write `xs = new ArrayList<Either<String, ?>>();`. When you actually construct an object, you have to give it concrete type parameters (including type variables already in scope), not wildcards or bounds. So while `asList` hides the explicit types, the compiler still has to choose one. It gives you a `List<Either<String, Object>>`, and then you upcast that to erase knowledge of the type.

Comment: @amalloy [Ok, except that works.](https://repl.it/repls/SophisticatedCavernousSquares) When you say `new ArrayList<Either<String, ?>>()`, you tell the new `ArrayList` that it will be containing `Either<String, ?>`s, each of which may have it's own choice of type for `?`. What doesn't work is `new ArrayList<?>()`, because *now* you've neglected to specify the type parameter. You've got your quantifier scopes all muddled. Also, an `ArrayList<Either<String, Object>>` *is not* a `ArrayList<Either<String, ?>>`, so it's definitely not a "concrete" version of the latter.

Comment: I see. I thought the rules against `new Foo<?>()` applied to `new Bar<Foo<?>>()` as well, but they do not. I'll have to think about what that means.

Comment: Based on your updated question, you definitely want [`Validation`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation). It’s like `Either` but accumulates errors instead of taking the first one, meant for exactly this kind of problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fruitless. `Either L R` where `R` is unknown is just `Maybe L`. If you have `Right (r :: R)` and put it into your list, thereby forgetting what `R` is, then even though you can later take that `Right r` out of the list, you will not know the type of `r`. That makes it unusable. The same is basically true in Java: a `Either<L, ?>` is really just an `Optional<L>`. If the `Either` *is* a `Right`, well, all you get is an `Object` (the upper bound of the wildcard). Ignoring the "universal" `Object` operations in Java (most importantly `instanceof` and `==`, but also `equals`, `hashCode`, `wait`, `synchronized`, etc.), none of which exist in Haskell (because Haskell values lack identity and runtime type), there's nothing you can do with this featureless blob. Why keep it in the first place?

Now, as to syntax: `_` wildcards in Haskell types are markers that you don't know what type goes there and you want GHC to infer it. I could write:

```
something :: [a] -> _
something = foldr (:) []
```

and GHC will tell me I should fill in the `_` with `[a]`, because that's the type of `something`. The `_` doesn't allow for anything "new"; it's just a convenience for when you don't know what the type of something is but you want to write it out for clarity (or when you don't want to write out the type because it's big, but that's rarer). In your case, `[foo, bar]` is ill-typed, period. Lists must be homogenous (contain elements of the same type) and `[foo, bar]` simply is not valid, and asking GHC to tell you what the type is not going to help you when there is no type in the first place.

The equivalent to Java's `?` types are existential types:

```
-- SomeEither l = Either<L, ?>
data SomeEither l = forall r. SomeEither (Either l r)
```

A `SomeEither l` (declared on the LHS) value is (according to the RHS) a pair, consisting of a type `r :: Type` and a value of type `Either l r`. This is also the meaning of `Either<L, ?>` in Java: `Either<L, ?>` is the type of pairs consisting of a type `R` (abusing the Java jargon, `R` is the "capture type") and a value `Either<L, R>`. However, in Java, the packing and unpacking of these pairs is implicit (packing is called "upcasting" and unpacking is called "wildcard capture"). In Haskell, you'd have to say

```
list = [SomeEither foo, SomeEither bar]
```

but now we're back to my first point that now you can never use the `Right`s ever again:

```
forM_ list (\(SomeEither x) ->
    case x of
        Left l -> putStrLn l
        Right r -> putStrLn ":(") -- don't know type of r; can't really use it for anything!
```

So, if you're going to have to preprocess the values before they go into the list, and if there's no point keeping the `Right` values around, then just get rid of them at the beginning:

```
list :: [Maybe String]
list = [left foo, left bar]
  where left = either Just (const Nothing)
-- or maybe you just want
list :: [String]
list = catMaybes [left foo, left bar]
  where left = either Just (const Nothing)
```

EDIT: "Putting things in lists" is 100% *not* the solution to your edited question. Note that even if you had wildcard types like in Java, they wouldn't really help, either. I think you actually want this `Applicative` (which is almost `WriterT [String] Maybe`):

```
newtype Validated a = Validated { runValidated :: Either [String] a }
  deriving Functor
instance Applicative Validated where
  pure = Validated . Right
  Validated l <*> Validated r = Validated (l <!> r)
    where
      Left xs <!> Left ys = Left (xs ++ ys)
      Left xs <!> Right _ = Left xs
      Right _ <!> Left xs = Left xs
      Right f <!> Right xs = Right (f xs)

parseStr :: [String] -> Validated String
parseDouble :: [String] -> Validated Double
parseBool :: [String] -> Validated Bool
parse :: [String] -> Validated Params
parse args = Params <$> parseStr args <*> parseDouble args <*> parseBool args
```

(Sadly, it's not a `Monad`.) No erasing of types, nothing fancy. Just combining all the errors and producing a value when there are none.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question to better reflect my problem, which might have not been clear enough. I disagree with you about "being fruitless". An `Either L R` where `R` is unknown is not equivalent to a `Maybe L`, because with an `Either` with unknown right value (if there was a support for such an abstraction) I could directly use functions that accept `Either`, while with `Maybe` I must convert it first, as you suggest. You can see in the examples I provided in my question that this leads to a more verbose and duplicate code. This is also the case with existential types.

Comment: @Whitetip Does the given `Applicative` satisfy your needs?

Comment: Your `Applicative` solution is very interesting, however it doesn't compile for me, even if I use `-XDeriveFunctor` flag. Can you please explain how this works?

Comment: @Whitetip Oops, fixed. It's actually the same as the other answer once you do that.

Comment: Thanks. :) `Applicative` is my new best friend.

Answer (score 2):

## New answer based on updated question

(Old answer below)

Based on the updated question, it sounds like a standard validation problem. This is essentially a FAQ, so I'll refer you to [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63346508/126014) for more details.

You can use `Applicative` to collect error messages, but for various reasons, the `Either` instance isn't suitable. What you can do is wrap `Either` in a `newtype` with a more appropriate `Applicative` instance and use that instead:

```
newtype Validation e r =
  Validation { runValidation :: Either e r } deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)

instance Semigroup m => Applicative (Validation m) where
  pure = Validation . pure
  Validation (Left x) <*> Validation (Left y) = Validation (Left (x <> y))
  Validation f <*> Validation r = Validation (f <*> r)
```

It'll also make things easier for you if you change the individual parsing functions to return `Validation` values:

```
parseStr :: String -> Validation [String] String
parseDouble :: String -> Validation [String] Double
parseBool :: String -> Validation [String] Bool
```

But if you don't want to do that, you can always lift `Either`-returning functions to `Validation` afterwards.

Now you can easily compose the desired `parse` function:

```
parse :: [String] -> Either [String] Params
parse [x, y, z] =
  runValidation $ Params <$> parseStr x <*> parseDouble y <*> parseBool z
parse _ = Left ["wrong number of arguments."]
```

There are [at least two reusable libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63346617/126014) that provide this functionality out of the box.

---

## Old answer

You can't put `Either String Int` and `Either String Char` values into the same list, because they don't have the same type. As *chi* suggests, you can wrap the `Right` values in an existential type, or perhaps just eliminate them by mapping all values to `Either String ()`.

If you're only looking for a way to collect all error messages, you can also use the `lefts` function.

Let's expand the example a bit:

```
import Data.Either

foo = Left "foo" :: Either String Int
bar = Left "bar" :: Either String Char
baz = Left "baz" :: Either String Char
qux = Right 42 :: Either String Int

list1 :: [Either String Int]
list1 = [foo, qux]

list2 :: [Either String Char]
list2 = [bar, baz]
```

You can put `foo` and `qux` in the same list, because they have the same type. The same goes for `bar` and `baz`.

You can pull out all the `Left` values of both lists and concatenate them:

```
errors :: [String]
errors = lefts list1 ++ lefts list2
```

Given the above values, `errors` has the value `["foo","bar","baz"]`. The number `42` isn't included, because that was a `Right` value.

I get the impression, however, that this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/135815). Which problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question to include more details about my actual problem. As you can see my point is using one list and not multiple lists. I understand that this is simply not possible to do in Haskell.

Comment: Thanks Mark, though it does require enabling some flags for it to compile.