# Collecting errors (instead of short-circuiting) until value is actually being used

Tags: haskell, error-handling, monads, applicative, semigroup

What's the simplest yet most elegant way to NOT short-circuit and instead collect errors until their values are used?

What's so hard in accumulating errors? Short circuit only if a function call receives an error value as value. But then return all errors accumulated since.

Insights:

- Monad short-circuits on any error because `>>=` relies on there being an argument to apply the function to.
- Applicative `<*>` can gather up errors from both of its arguments.

**The code does not compile (see compiling error below) due to missing Monad instance as I don’t know how it needs to be designed. The code is intended to show the desired behaviour that a Monad instance or any other implementation should provide.**

**This is a request for a specific code solution (be it Monad instance or an entirely different approach) and *NOT* for a package recommendation.**

Still the approaches used in following language extensions and packages might give some inspiration (parts emerged in #haskell IRC):

- [monad-validate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-validate)
- [validation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation)
- [these](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/these)
- ApplicativeDo
- Writer Monad

The following code is inspired by:
[How is it possible to collect all error messages in the Either Monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63346279)
https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/11/05/applicative-validation/

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, RecordWildCards, OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text (Text)

newtype Errors e r = Errors (Either e r) deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)

instance Semigroup m => Applicative (Errors m) where
  pure = Errors . pure
  Errors (Left x) <*> Errors (Left y) = Errors (Left (x <> y))
  Errors f <*> Errors r = Errors (f <*> r)

data Result = Result {r1 :: !Int, rg :: !Int} deriving (Show)

f1 :: Errors [Text] Int
f1 = Errors $ Left ["f1 failed"]

f2 :: Errors [Text] Int
f2 = pure 2

f3 :: Errors [Text] Int
f3 = Errors $ Left ["f3 failed"]

f4 :: Errors [Text] Int
f4 = pure 4

f5 :: Errors [Text] Int
f5 = pure 5

g :: Int -> Int -> Errors [Text] Int
g a b | a + b <= 6 = Errors $ Left ["g: a + b NOT > 6"] -- we'll let `g` fail if sum is less than 6
      | otherwise = pure $ a * b

-- | in `scenario1` `g` uses one erroneous and one non-erroneous result.
--   since `g` tries to consume one erroneous result `r3` `g` can't execute.
--   it short-circuits the computation.
--   all up till then collected errors are returned.
--
-- >>> scenario1
-- Errors (Left ["f1 failed", "f3 failed"])
scenario1 :: Errors [Text] Result
scenario1 = do
  r1 <- f1 :: Errors [Text] Int -- fails, collected
  r2 <- f2 :: Errors [Text] Int -- succeeds
  r3 <- f3 :: Errors [Text] Int -- fails, collected
  -- we haven’t short-circuited until here, instead collected errors
  -- although `f1` failed, `f2` and `f3` still have been executed
  -- but now we need to short circuit on `f4` because at least any of `r2` or `r3` has error value
  rg <- g r2 r3 :: Errors [Text] Int
  pure $ Result {..}

-- | `g` can execute (all values are non-errors) but `g` itself produces an error.
--   computation short-circuits only on construction of `Result`.
--   that is because `Result` only carries non-error values but `g` produced error value.
--   `scenario2` returns error values of `f1` and `g`.
--
-- >>> scenario2
-- Errors (Left ["f1 failed", "g: a + b NOT > 6"])
scenario2:: Errors [Text] Result
scenario2 = do
  r1 <- f1 :: Errors [Text] Int -- fails, collected
  r2 <- f2 :: Errors [Text] Int -- succeeds
  r4 <- f4 :: Errors [Text] Int -- succeeds
  -- we haven’t short-circuited until here, instead collected errors
  -- although `f1` failed, `f2` and `f4` still have been executed
  -- `g` receives non-error values `r2` and `r4` with values 2 and 4
  -- now, g itself returns an error due to its logic
  rg <- g r2 r4 :: Errors [Text] Int
  -- we still don’t short-circuit `g`'s error being produced
  -- we only short-circuit on the error value tried being used by `Result`:
  pure $ Result {..}

-- | `g` does neither is fed with erroneous values nor
--   does `g` itself return an error. Instead construction of `Result` fails
--   since it tries to load value of `r1` which is erroneous but should be `Int`.
--
-- >>> scenario3
-- Errors (Left ["f1 failed"])
scenario3 :: Errors [Text] Result
scenario3 = do
  r1 <- f1 :: Errors [Text] Int -- fails, collected
  r2 <- f2 :: Errors [Text] Int -- succeeds
  r5 <- f5 :: Errors [Text] Int -- succeeds
  -- we haven’t short-circuited until here, instead collected errors
  -- although `f1` failed, `f2` and `f4` still have been executed
  -- `g` receives non-error values `r2` and `r5` with values 2 and 5
  -- now, `g` itself succeeds, no error
  rg <- g r2 r5 :: Errors [Text] Int
  -- `Result` is constructed, since `f1` failed, `r1` is of error value now
  -- hence `Result` cannot be constructed, failure "f1 failed" should be returned
  pure $ Result {..}

-- | no error anywhere, 
--
-- >>> scenario4
-- Errors (Right 7)
scenario4 :: Errors [Text] Result
scenario4 = do
  r1 <- f4 :: Errors [Text] Int -- succeeds
  r2 <- f2 :: Errors [Text] Int -- succeeds
  r5 <- f5 :: Errors [Text] Int -- succeeds
  -- now, `g` itself succeeds, no error
  rg <- g r2 r5 :: Errors [Text] Int
  -- `Result` is constructed successfully because it only takes in non-error values
  pure $ Result {..}
```

And here comes the error:

```
rc/MyLib2.hs:42:3: error: [GHC-39999]
    • No instance for ‘Monad (Errors [Text])’
        arising from a do statement
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: r1 <- f1 :: Errors [Text] Int
      In the expression:
        do r1 <- f1 :: Errors [Text] Int
           r2 <- f2 :: Errors [Text] Int
           r3 <- f3 :: Errors [Text] Int
           rg <- g r2 r3 :: Errors [Text] Int
           ....
      In an equation for ‘scenario1’:
          scenario1
            = do r1 <- f1 :: Errors [Text] Int
                 r2 <- f2 :: Errors [Text] Int
                 r3 <- f3 :: Errors [Text] Int
                 ....
   |
42 |   r1 <- f1 :: Errors [Text] Int -- fails, collected
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: notice in `scenario1` the value `r3` is an `Int` (from compiler's point of view). Therefore, when calling `g r2 r3` we can't say: _oh!, `r3` is an error, hence let's not execute `g`_, Are  you confused by syntatic sugar of `do` notation maybe??. Between line `r3 <- f3` and next line `rg <- g r2 r3` there is a call to `>>=`. Unfortunatelly your code doesn't provide any `Monad` instance for `Errors`

Comment: Requests for library or tool suggestions aren't on-topic here. They're too hard to keep up-to-date, and often just a matter of opinion at any given time anyway.

Comment: @DanielWagner How is this is a request for a library or a tool?

Comment: [There is no lawful `Monad` instance consistent with the `Applicative (Validation e)` instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40539650/791604) (which you have replicated here in this code). So you are asking for an alternative to the `validation` package that makes other tradeoffs.

Comment: This looks like an `Applicative` plus an explicit `join`-like operation to handle calls to functions like `g` with the caveat that this "`join`" doesn't match the `Applicative` (cf., the `bindValidation` function in the `validation` package).  As a result, I think it can probably be answered without appealing to a library or package.  So, I'd vote for reopening.

Answer (score 5):

What I've been doing so far in situations like this isn't particularly sophisticated. It's possible that there's a more elegant way to do this with Haskell, but on the other hand, what follows here can be ported to other languages.

The way I address these sorts of problems is that I alternate between two representations of the same data; one which has validation-like behaviour, and one which is a proper monad.

For the monad it's obvious to use the built-in `Either`. For the validation representation, I'll here use `Errors` provided in the OP.

These two representations are isomorphic, but it's probably convenient to have explicit functions to go back and forth:

```
toEither :: Errors l r -> Either l r
toEither = coerce

fromEither :: Either l r -> Errors l r
fromEither = coerce
```

Furthermore, I'm also going to take advantage of this extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ApplicativeDo #-}
```

With these additions, we can implement each of the scenarios in the OP.

## Scenario 1

Most of these scenarios have similar-looking code, so I'm going to mostly comment on the first one:

```
scenario1 :: Errors [Text] Result
scenario1 = do
  r1 <- f1
  rg <- fromEither $ do
        r2 <- toEither f2
        r3 <- toEither f3
        toEither $ g r2 r3
  pure $ Result r1 rg
```

The outer `do` expression uses `Errors`, which is why we need the `ApplicativeDo` extension. While `Errors` is not a `Monad` instance, that extension still enables the `do` syntax.

In order to compose `r2` and `r3` together with `g`, you'll need some kind of `join` functionality, so the inner `do` works in normal `Either`-monad mode by converting the values, and then converting the result back to `Errors`.

It may not be the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
ghci> scenario1
Errors (Left ["f1 failed","f3 failed"])
```

## Scenario 2

This one, and the subsequent examples, follows the same template:

```
scenario2 :: Errors [Text] Result
scenario2 = do
  r1 <- f1
  rg <- fromEither $ do
        r2 <- toEither f2
        r4 <- toEither f4
        toEither $ g r2 r4
  pure $ Result r1 rg
```

Demo:

```
ghci> scenario2
Errors (Left ["f1 failed","g: a + b NOT > 6"])
```

## Scenario 3

Code:

```
scenario3 :: Errors [Text] Result
scenario3 = do
  r1 <- f1
  rg <- fromEither $ do
        r2 <- toEither f2
        r5 <- toEither f5
        toEither $ g r2 r5
  pure $ Result r1 rg
```

Demo:

```
ghci> scenario3
Errors (Left ["f1 failed"])
```

## Scenario 4

Code:

```
scenario4 :: Errors [Text] Result
scenario4 = do
  r1 <- f4
  rg <- fromEither $ do
        r2 <- toEither f2
        r5 <- toEither f5
        toEither $ g r2 r5
  pure $ Result r1 rg
```

Demo:

```
ghci> scenario4
Errors (Right (Result {r1 = 4, rg = 10}))
```

Answer (score 1):

@MarkSeemann's approach works pretty well, but after fiddling around with a few designs, I think you can get the cleanest syntax by simply using a `Writer` monad with `Maybe` values:

```
type Errors e a = Writer e (Maybe a)
```

Note here that the `Writer` layer is *not* a transformer.  This is a plain old writer monad whose values are lifted into `Maybe`.  You write `do`-notation for the `Writer`, which takes care of collecting error messages, but the values you extract from the monad are always `Maybe` values that allow you to carry around multiple failed computations as `Nothing`s where the cause of the failure has already been logged to the `Writer`.

So, in your `do`-blocks, a statement like:

```
r1 <- f1
```

is running an `f1 :: Error [Text] Int` computation to yield an `r1 :: Maybe Int` value.  (Again, `r1` is *not* an `Int`.  All the extracted values are lifted into `Maybe`.)  When you have a function like `g` that takes unlifted values but can generate its own errors:

```
g :: Int -> Int -> Errors [Text] Int
```

you use an adapter to explicitly mark the function as requiring its arguments to be present:

```
r1 <- f1
r2 <- f2
r3 <- f3
rg <- call2 g r2 r3  -- `call2` adapter ensures r2/r3 are present
```

You can also lift pure functions like `(,)` or the `Result` constructor from your example with additional adapters:

```
liftE2 Result r1 rg  -- `liftE2` lifts Result :: Int -> Int -> Result
```

The resulting scenarios look pretty clean.  For example:

```
f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 :: Errors [String] Int
f1 = err "f1 failed"
f2 = yield 2
f3 = err "f3 failed"
f4 = yield 4
f5 = yield 5

g :: Int -> Int -> Errors [Text] Int
g a b | a + b <= 6 = err "g: a + b NOT > 6"
      | otherwise = yield $ a * b

scenario1 :: Errors [String] Result
scenario1 = do
  r1 <- f1
  r2 <- f2
  r3 <- f3
  rg <- call2 g r2 r3
  liftE2 Result r1 rg
```

and the adapters are straightforward, if tedious:

```
call2 :: (Monoid e) => (a1 -> a2 -> Errors e r) -> Maybe a1 -> Maybe a2 -> Errors e r
call2 f x1 x2    = makeCall (f <$> x1 <*> x2)
    where makeCall = fromMaybe (pure Nothing)

liftE2 :: (Monoid e) => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> (Maybe a1 -> Maybe a2 -> Errors e r)
liftE2 f x1 x2    = pure (f <$> x1 <*> x2)
```

A complete example with more arities of adapters defined:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Collect where

import Data.Text
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)
import Control.Monad.Writer

type Errors e a = Writer e (Maybe a)

runErrors :: Errors e a -> Either e a
runErrors act = case runWriter act of
  (Nothing, e) -> Left e
  (Just x, _)  -> Right x

err :: t -> Errors [t] a
err t = errs [t]

errs :: (Monoid e) => e -> Errors e a
errs e = tell e >> pure Nothing

yield :: (Monoid e) => a -> Errors e a
yield = pure . Just

call  :: (Monoid e) => (a1             -> Errors e r) -> Maybe a1                         -> Errors e r
call2 :: (Monoid e) => (a1 -> a2       -> Errors e r) -> Maybe a1 -> Maybe a2             -> Errors e r
call3 :: (Monoid e) => (a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> Errors e r) -> Maybe a1 -> Maybe a2 -> Maybe a3 -> Errors e r
call  f x1       = makeCall (f <$> x1)
call2 f x1 x2    = makeCall (f <$> x1 <*> x2)
call3 f x1 x2 x3 = makeCall (f <$> x1 <*> x2 <*> x3)

makeCall :: (Monoid e) => Maybe (Writer e (Maybe a)) -> Writer e (Maybe a)
makeCall = fromMaybe (pure Nothing)

liftE  :: (Monoid e) => (a1             -> r) -> (Maybe a1                         -> Errors e r)
liftE2 :: (Monoid e) => (a1 -> a2       -> r) -> (Maybe a1 -> Maybe a2             -> Errors e r)
liftE3 :: (Monoid e) => (a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> r) -> (Maybe a1 -> Maybe a2 -> Maybe a3 -> Errors e r)
liftE  f x1       = pure (f <$> x1)
liftE2 f x1 x2    = pure (f <$> x1 <*> x2)
liftE3 f x1 x2 x3 = pure (f <$> x1 <*> x2 <*> x3)

data Result = Result {r1 :: !Int, rg :: !Int} deriving (Show)

f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 :: Errors [Text] Int
f1 = err "f1 failed"
f2 = yield 2
f3 = err "f3 failed"
f4 = yield 4
f5 = yield 5

g :: Int -> Int -> Errors [Text] Int
g a b | a + b <= 6 = err "g: a + b NOT > 6"
      | otherwise = yield $ a * b

scenario1 :: Errors [Text] Result
scenario1 = do
  r1 <- f1
  r2 <- f2
  r3 <- f3
  rg <- call2 g r2 r3
  liftE2 Result r1 rg

scenario2 :: Errors [Text] Result
scenario2 = do
  r1 <- f1
  r2 <- f2
  r4 <- f4
  rg <- call2 g r2 r4
  liftE2 Result r1 rg

scenario3 :: Errors [Text] Result
scenario3 = do
  r1 <- f1
  r2 <- f2
  r5 <- f5
  rg <- call2 g r2 r5
  liftE2 Result r1 rg

scenario4 :: Errors [Text] Result
scenario4 = do
  r1 <- f4
  r2 <- f2
  r5 <- f5
  rg <- call2 g r2 r5
  liftE2 Result r1 rg

main = mapM_ (print . runErrors) [scenario1, scenario2, scenario3, scenario4]
```